# re-bounty option for bounties with no answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I recently placed a 50-rep bounty on a question, which received no additional input.

Is there anyway to reapply the bounty or do the rep points evaporate?

Comment: Since this is tagged feature-request, I'll add my opinion that re-application of bounty should *not* be an option. An OP pays with bounty, not for answers, but for up to 7 (actually 8) days of extra visibility of the question. This service was rendered, and payment received.

Comment: @user31373, That seems fair.  Still sucks, but it's fair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ on bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties):

If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically be awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. **If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.**

Comment: I have always wondered what is the rationale for such a pretty weird rule...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez LVK's comment already explains it.  Are you saying you don't think that's enough?  I guess one could argue that, though the question received more publicity, it didn't receive enough if there were no answers.  So, it wasn't really helped by the bounty and it should be returned.  Is that what you're thinking?

Comment: I am just saying that the rule that an answer may get accepted even against the bounty-offerer wanting to award to that answer, and that bounties expire automatically after a time (that the offerer loses the rep is even weirder...) The two parts of these rule appear pretty absurd to me, and extending deadlines is not helping this in my view.

Comment: @Mariano As of this moment, StackOverflow has 366 "featured" questions which almost defeats the purpose of them being featured. MSE has a reasonable number at this time, but allowing non-expiring bounties would quickly bring us there. The bottom line is, it's impossible to put the spotlight on many things at once; so something must be done to control prolific bounty setters (such as myself :).

Comment: A better algorithm to define what is in the spotlight might help (show the last 10 bounties and a rotating list of other, older bounties, say, for some appropriate value of 10) but mathematical questions can be *hard*... Imagine Fermat setting a bounty for a cool proof of his theorem! As usual, One Size Fits All never works that well.

Comment: I agree with the bounties expiring and the bounty points being lost if not awarded. But the original questions/problem posted by the OP is reasonable. Why not to allow opening the bounty again, expending  more reputation on it, if there were no answers to the question? Better to put reputation to good use than the banal accumulation of it.